# Counting independent components of Lorentz tensor

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, covariance, invariants

Say I have Lorentz tensors $A^{\mu\nu}$ and say this Lorentz tensor is symmetric under $\mu \Leftrightarrow \nu$ and there are only $p^\mu$ and $q^\mu$ as the physical Lorentz vectors involved. If so, then $A^{\mu\nu}$ can be parameterized simply in terms of these vectors as

$$A^{\mu\nu} = g^{\mu\nu}A_1 + p^\mu p^\nu A_2 + q^\mu q^\nu A_3 + (p^\mu q^\nu+q^\mu p^\nu) A_4 $$

Thus, $A^{\mu\nu}$ have four-independent components. This kind of exercise is well-known, for example, in DIS structure functions parameterization, etc. Imposing Ward Identities (if available) would reduce the number of independent components even further.

Say instead, I have Lorentz tensors with four indices. $A^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ which is symmetric under $\mu \Leftrightarrow \nu$ and $\rho \Leftrightarrow \sigma$. Also, assume that there are only $p^\mu$ and $q^\mu$ as the available Lorentz vectors. The general parameterization has quite a bit of structures: $\{qqqq,qqqp,qqpp,qppp,pppp,gqq,gpp,gqp,gg\}$. Taking this full space of parameterization then imposing symmetries to reduce the number of independent components is a bit cumbersome (and certainly becomes less tractable if I consider a case with even more than four indices). How should I do the counting? Also, my intuition tells me I can just factorize this tensor into a product $A^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = B^{\mu\nu} C^{\rho\sigma}$, then parameterize $B^{\mu\nu}$ and $C^{\rho\sigma}$ separately into four symmetric structures, giving one total of 16 independent components. Is this correct?

Edit: one cannot use factorized product form to parameterize. For example, $$g^{\mu \sigma}  g^{\nu \rho}  + g^{\mu \rho} g^{\nu\sigma}$$ is an example of the tensor structure which is symmetric under $\mu \Leftrightarrow \nu$ and $\rho \Leftrightarrow \sigma$, but is not given in factorized product form.

Comment: I will be interested to see if there's a systematic way to do this.  For a paper a few years back, I did similar sorts of enumerations for rank-4 through rank-6 tensors in the presence of a single vector field;  but I ended up doing them all by hand.  My instinct is saying that there's a way to do this with Young tableaux but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: I see.... which paper is this? I guess doing this exercise with single vector field will simplify it quite a bit though. Do you agree that I would get the same answer as doing it from $B$ and $C$ independently and multiplying them?

Comment: Class. Quantum Grav. **37** 065022 (arxiv 1907.12595.)  My gut instinct is that you might be able to do the $BC$ factorization you describe;  but I don't think you'll end up with 16 components this way.  Note, for example, that there's a degeneracy in this parametrization since you can multiply $B$ by a constant and divide $C$ by the same constant without changing $A$. There may be other degeneracies that arise in the cross-terms as well.

Comment: Well, I don't think overall constants matter. I'm only trying to count the independent Lorentz structures: if I have $$(...)^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} B_1 C_1$$, I might as well combine $$B_1  C_1$$ and call it $$A_1$$ structure. The degeneracy you describe is not physical

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150333/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-quantization).